# Выполнение php скрипта в фоновом режиме

Tags: php

Как выполнять php скрипт в фоновом режиме и без Cron, возможно ли это?

Answer (score 2):

возможно речь об этом

> http://habrahabr.ru/post/134620/

хотя я не уверен

Comment: Если не уверены, лучше в комментарии писать. В ответе к тому же не приветствуются только ссылки - лучше скопировать основные подходящие части материала по ссылке в ответ.

Comment: я все же надеюсь что вопрос будет более раскрыт автором

Comment: Не уверен, что стоит передерать статьи, или их части.
Отличный ответ. 
Stackoverflow всегда был справочником - короткий вопрос, короткий ответ.
Хабр же учебник.
Давайте каждый будет заниматься тем, что умеет, не вижу смысла переписывать то, что хорошо написано)
Что делать с любителями велосипедов не знаю)

Comment: в таком случае мне написать название технологии? так как не любой ответ может быть кратким